# Prove that a number is the product of two primes under certain conditions.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

*Suppose $p$ be the smallest prime dividing $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Prove that if $n$ is not a perfect square and that $p<n<p^3$, then $n$ must be the product of two primes.*

Clearly, the smallest $p$ can be is $2$ and $n$ must be an integer that is greater than $1$ in order to be divisible by a prime. I know that the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (FTA) guarantees that every positive integer greater than $1$ is the product of two or more primes. So is it enough to argue that by the FTA, $n$ is the product of two primes?

Comment: "I know that the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (FTA) guarantees that every positive integer greater than 1 is the product of two distinct primes."  Nonsense.  What about $42 = 2*3*7$.  That's the product of *three* distinct primes.  Not two.

Comment: Sorry, misread the theorem. I fixed it in the description.

Comment: @FoiledIt24 A composite number must be the product of two or more primes (not necessarily distinct), but that's not true of prime numbers.

Comment: "I know that the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (FTA) guarantees that every positive integer greater than 1 is the product of two or more primes. "  Still nonsense.  What about $17 = 1*17$.  That's not the product of two or more primes.

Comment: "So is it enough to argue that by the FTA, n is the product of two primes?" Of course not.  First of all that is trivially true of all composites so if that was enough this was be true for all composites.  But that isn't what is asked.  You have to prove $n$ is the product of *exactly* two primes.

Comment: It's got noting to do with FTA and FTA won't help you.  $n$ has specific properties that other number don't have.

Answer (score 2):

The FTA doesn't say what you think it does, so let's be more formal about $n$'s prime factorisation. Since $n$ is neither a perfect power of $p$ nor large enough to be a product of the form $pqr$, $p^2q$ or $pq^2$ with primes $q,\,r$ distinct primes greater than $p$, it must instead be of the form $pq$.

Comment: I corrected the question, now $p^2<n<p^3$

Comment: @WillJagy My answer is unchanged.

Comment: huh. You're right at that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet one more way to see that your proposition is true:

1. $n\ne p$ because $p<n$
2. $n\ne p^2$ because $n$ is not a perfect square
3. $n\ne p^3$ because $n<p^3$

Hence, $n$ has one or more other prime factors.

4. Assume $n$ has one additional (larger) prime factor, $q=p+a$. Then $n=pq=p^2+ap$, which is less than $p^3$ whenever $a<p^2-p$
5. Assume $n$ has two additional (larger) prime factors, $q=p+a$ and $r=p+b$. Then $n=pqr=p^3+(a+b)p^2+abp>p^3$, which necessarily contradicts the assumption $n<p^3$

Plainly, even more prime factors of $n$ only makes the issue in point 5 worse. So the only possibility not ruled out is 4, which is what you set out to prove.

Answer (score 0):

If $p|n$ and $p < n < p^3$ then $1 < \frac np < p^2$ and $\frac np$ is an integer.

Consider what prime factors can divide $\frac np$.  No prime less than $p$ as $p$ was the smallest prime dividing $n$.

If $p|\frac np$ then we $\frac n{p^2} < p$ but $n$ has no non trivial factors less than $p$ so $\frac n{p^2} =1$ and $n = p^2$.  But $n$ is not a perfect square.

So there is a prime $q > p$ so that $q|\frac np$.  But then $\frac n{pq} < \frac {p^2}q=p\frac pq < p*1 =p$.  But $n$ has no non trivial factors less than $p$.  So $\frac n{pq} = 1$ and $n =pq$ and $pq$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p^3 > n$ then
$p > n^{1/3}$
so
$\dfrac{n}{p}
\lt \dfrac{n}{n^{1/3}}
=n^{2/3}
$.

If another prime
$q > p$ divides $n$,
then
$q | \dfrac{n}{p}
$
so
$q \lt \dfrac{n}{p}
\lt n^{2/3}
$
and
$q > p > n^{1/3}$.

Therefore
$\dfrac{n}{pq}
\lt n^{1/3}$.

No other prime can divide
$\dfrac{n}{pq}$
since that is less than
$n^{1/3}$
and no prime smaller than $p$
divides $n$.

Therefore
$n = pq$.